# Вывод данных с $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

Здравствуйте, отправляю кросс доменный запрос. Он проходит, но в ответ мне сервер посылает данные в json формате, вида:

```
{"Name":"Ivan","LastName":"Petrov"}
```

и я никак не могу их вывести.
код такой

```
 $.getJSON('https://сайт.ру?login=Sergey&password=qwerty&callback=?',function(data){
  alert("Otvet: " + data.Name);
});
```

alert вообще не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

```
           $.ajax({
             url:'https://сайт.ру/register.do?',
             dataType:'jsonp',
             data:{userName:'Sergey',password:'qwerty'},
             success:function(res) {
             alert(res);
          }
            });
```

Comment: если вы точно уверерны, что ваш запрос проходит и вы получаете ответ, то попробуйте вместо alert(...) использовать console.log(data) - проверьте результат в консоли FireBug

Comment: Да, запрос точно проходит и ответ приходит, но почему то алерт не срабатывает, т.е. никак не могу получить ответ от сервера . Смотрел в средстве разработчика, которое встроено в chrome

Comment: ну в консоле firebug ошибка : SyntaxError: invalid label и ответ от сервера вида {"Name":"Ivan","LastName":"Petrov"}
а в консоле chrome : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: вместо `$.getJSON` используйте просто `$.ajax` c `dataTyle:'jsonp'`

Comment: Попробовал вот так :
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://сайт.ру?callback=? ',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {login:'Sergey',password:'qwerty'},
        jsonpCallback: 'my_callback_func',
});
function my_callback_func(result) {
alert (result);
}

Тоже самое - запрос проходит, ответ есть, а алерт не работает... А мне нужно любым способом достать ответ: либо присвоить какой-нибудь переменной, либо вывести алертом на экран

Comment: Может быть [это поможет](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3_json-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте данные на наглядность в Chrome Developer Tools вкладка Network И нажимайте там на свои кнопки - важно что бы там появился новый запрос на указанный адрес . Во вкладках посмотрите что за ключи отсылаются, и что за данная приходит.. Попробуйте распарсить ее на сайтах очищающих сам JSON. Ибо сдается мне что вы совсем не такого формата получаете ответ от сервера иначе JS не орал бы вам в лицо что это совсем не JSON.

Еще более важно - посмотреть на какой строчке и в каком скрипте сама ошибка.. Потому что если это в самом jQuery тогда это точно не JSON. 
Проверьте так же кодировку - с cp1251(aka windows-1251) json_encode не работает корректно...

Comment: Посмотрел, что выдает chrome :
Query String Parameters
:
callback:jQuery17205258336188271642_1349115500910
userName:Sergey
password:qwerty
_:1349115504110
Возможно это вот это двоеточие (1 строчка). На которое ругается.
Ответ пробовал парсить на сайте json parser online - нормально распарсило. Так что проблема не в ответе .

Код обновил. Если убрать в ссылке https://сайт.ру/register.do? вопросительный знак, то двоеточие пропадет, но запрос проходить не будет.Вот в этом случае запрос приходит, ответ тоже, но к сожалению вытащить этот ответ я не могу ( не проходит в success - алерт не работает

Answer (score 2):

А почему никто не подумал о том, что если хочется JSONP, то сервер должен возвращать примерно такое:

```
jquery940394039403({"Name":"Ivan","LastName":"Petrov"})
```

Ну хоть кто-нибудь вообще читал спецификацию JSONP?

Comment: дело в том, что управление не переходит сюда:
   success:function(res) {
             alert(res);
          } Поэтому я не могу вывести ответ сервера на экран ..